# SPWebConfigModification - Features over writing each other modification

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using log4Net with share point 2010. I have a feature which automatically adds the log4net config when my soultion is deployed in Error mode using following code

```
SPWebService service = SPWebService.ContentService;

            service.WebConfigModifications.Clear();
  //ADD log4Net config section
            service.WebConfigModifications.Add(new SPWebConfigModification()
            {
                Path = "configuration/configSections",
                Name = "section[@name='log4net']",
                Sequence = 0,
                Owner = CREATE_NAME,
                Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode,
                Value = string.Format(@"<section name='log4net' type='log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version={0}, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={1}' />", LOG4NET_VERSION, LOG4NET_PUBLIC_KEY_TOKEN)
            });


            string log4netConfig = @"<log4net>
                                        <appender name='RollingFileAppender' type='log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender'>
                                            <file value='C:\\logs\\Logger.log' />
                                            <appendToFile value='true' />
                                            <rollingStyle value='Composite' />
                                            <datePattern value='yyyyMMdd' />
                                            <maxSizeRollBackups value='200' />
                                            <maximumFileSize value='50MB' />
                                            <layout type='log4net.Layout.PatternLayout'>
                                                <conversionPattern value='%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] &lt;%X{auth}&gt; - %m%n' />
                                            </layout>
                                        </appender>
                                        <root>
                                          <level value='ERROR' />
                                          <appender-ref ref='RollingFileAppender' />
                                        </root>
                                    </log4net>";
            //add error default config
            service.WebConfigModifications.Add(new SPWebConfigModification()
            {
                Path = "configuration",
                Name = "log4net",
                Sequence = 0,
                Owner = CREATE_NAME,
                Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode,
                Value = log4netConfig
            });

service.Update();
            service.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
```

I wanted to create another feature which over writes Error mode of the log4net and change it to debug, so that the end user does not have to modifiy web config manually.
The problem is when the second feature is activated, it deletes everything added by the first feature.

Is this standard behaviour ?? Any feature that would activate would delete the changes by other feature.

**EDIT 2**

*Steps to replicate*

Create 2 feature. both of them should add some different entries in web config.

1. Activate feature 1 - Feature 1 changes are in web config
2. Activate feature 2 - Feature 2 changes are in web config but feature 1
   changes are gone

Deactivate both the features

1. Activate feature 2 - Feature 2 changes are in web config
2. Activate feature 1 - Feature 1 changes are in web config but feature
   2 changes are gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the first web configuration is removed is because of the code block:

```
service.WebConfigModifications.Clear();
```

Basically you're saying that you will be clearing all other configurations set in your web  config prior to adding the items in your feature. Removing the said code block should fix your issue.

If you need to do some other things when activating or deactivating a feature try using Feature Receivers. A good example to start with web configurations and feature receivers can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/01/21/web.config-modifications-with-a-sharepoint-feature.aspx).

Also to give you more idea on the code block above is giving you problems you can check out the problem another guy which had the similar problem [here](http://www.tonytestasworld.com/post/2009/05/21/Be-cautious-when-using-e2809cSPWebApplicationWebConfigModificationsClear%28%29e2809d-method-because-it-can-clear-out-ALL-webconfig-modifications-not-just-your-own.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Lemme check it once and I would get back to you.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully this fixes your issue. If not please let me know.

Comment: Ah, it worked fine. I started writing this feature by copying another feature and this thing floated in. thanks for your help. +50

Answer (score 0):

if I understand this correctly, what's happening is you add a webconfigmodification, this isn't technically "added" yet as it is hasn't been implemented just yet. When you created the 2nd modification, it overwrites the first modification you created, which in turns, erases the first modification that was made, and this was the one that was applied.

Comment: Why do you believe so ? In my code I am calling update and apply methods to make the change persist. 
Did you tried to replicate the issue ?

Comment: I'm not really sure honestly, that's just how i see the code, i've encountered a similar style before but not exactly the same lines of code.

Comment: Well this is a bit hard to digest. Because call to save config and apply config has been made. 
Anyways thanks for your help

Comment: refer to this link, tried to make a bit of research, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/390545/SharePoint-web-config-modifications and refer to this part SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications